# XML Data into my Database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

It has been a long time since I have been a coder and I am getting set with something 
I know is really simple.

I am trying to access an XML Page of products and insert them into my database.

The code I have produced is giving me the following error message:

```
Unknown column '10074' in 'field list'
```

10074 is the Product ID of the first item.

The code is below.

Can you point me in the right direction with this as it is really getting to me.

Many thanks in advance!

```
<?php
   $Products = simplexml_load_file('http://atsdistribution.co.uk/feeds/xml_all_products.aspx');


$con = mysql_connect(*****);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("catflaps_products", $con);


foreach($Products->Product as $Product)
{
$ProductID = $Product->ProductID;
$Name = $Product->Name;
$DropshipPrice = $Product->DropshipPrice;
$SRP = $Product->SRP;
$Brand = $Product->Brand;
$Xline = $Product->Xline;
$InStock = $Product->InStock;
$Stock = $Product->Stock;
$Barcode = $Product->Barcode;
$Weight = $Product->Weight;
$CategoryID = $Product->CategoryID;
$Category = $Product->Category;
$SmallImage = $Product->SmallImage;
$LargeImage = $Product->LargeImage;
$Description = $Product->Description;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(ProductID, Name, DropshipPrice, SRP, Brand, Xline, InStock, Stock, Barcode, Weight, CategoryID, Category, SmallImage, LargeImage, Description)
VALUES(`$ProductID`, `$Name` , `$DropshipPrice`, `$SRP`, `$Brand`, `$Xline`, `$InStock`, `$Stock`, `$Barcode`, `$Weight`, `$CategoryID`, `$Category`, `$SmallImage`, `$LargeImage`, `$Description`)")
        or die(mysql_error());

}

mysql_close($con);
// some code

?>
```

Comment: The problem does not seem with this part of the code. It is probably where you are parsing the xml!

Comment: The code seems to be ok. Check if there is not a typo error in original like `"INSERT INTO test($ProductID,`

Answer (score 0):

most likely it is the parsing of the xml. make sure you call mysql_real_escape_string to sanitize your data.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 'backtick' (`) to quote your values, MySQL therefore sees them as 'column names'. Using regular 'single' quotes (') should probably solve your problem